# How to make more tkinter buttons in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I am making a PC helper program with a gui for a school project. I have added two buttons but I cant seem to add more than two...

Here is the code:

```
#All imports go here
import tkinter as tk
import os

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello, what would you like help with today?"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.notepad = tk.Button(self)
        self.notepad["text"] = "Launch Notepad"
        self.notepad["command"] = self.notepad
        self.notepad.pack(side="right")

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi["text"] = "Launch CMD"
        self.hi["command"] = self.cmd
        self.hi.pack(side="left") 

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                          command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def cmd(self):
        os.system("start cmd /a")

    def notepad(self):
        os.system("start notepad")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()

sys.exit()
```

Comment: What happens if you try to add more than two buttons?

Comment: @halfer if you happen to notice it's missing, please add the generic python tag when you edit questions tagged [python-y.x]. Thanks!

Comment: @Andras: will do, yes - will try to spot it `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Two created buttons are definded here:

```
def create_widgets(self):
    self.hi = tk.Button(self)
    self.hi["text"] = "Launch CMD"
    self.hi["command"] = self.cmd
    self.hi.pack(side="left")

    self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                      command=root.destroy)
    self.quit.pack(side="bottom")
```

But why only these are created?
Answer is simple, look comments in code below:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.create_widgets2()
        self.create_widgets3()

    def create_widgets(self):  # define
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello, what would you like help with today?"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi  # additional bug (AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'say_hi'), change this to "self.hi_there["command"] = self.hi_there"
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

    def create_widgets(self):  # re-define without usage
        self.notepad = tk.Button(self)
        self.notepad["text"] = "Launch Notepad"
        self.notepad["command"] = self.notepad
        self.notepad.pack(side="right")

    def create_widgets(self):  # again re-define without usage
        self.hi = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi["text"] = "Launch CMD"
        self.hi["command"] = self.cmd
        self.hi.pack(side="left")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def cmd(self):
        os.system("start cmd /a")

    def notepad(self):
        os.system("start notepad")
```

This code gives the same efect as code below.

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.pack()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    self.hi = tk.Button(self)
    self.hi["text"] = "Launch CMD"
    self.hi["command"] = self.cmd
    self.hi.pack(side="left")

    self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                      command=root.destroy)
    self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

def cmd(self):
    os.system("start cmd /a")

def notepad(self):
    os.system("start notepad")
```

Defining functions is similar to assigning the variable value:

```
a = 1
a = 4
a = 150
print(a)  # will print 150, not 1, 4, 150
```

So you should put all the buttons (other widgets in future too) in the same function or change the function names and call them in the *init* function.

Working code (first way, better in my opinion):

```
import tkinter as tk
import os


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello, what would you like help with today?"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.hi_there
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.notepad = tk.Button(self)
        self.notepad["text"] = "Launch Notepad"
        self.notepad["command"] = self.notepad
        self.notepad.pack(side="right")

        self.hi = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi["text"] = "Launch CMD"
        self.hi["command"] = self.cmd
        self.hi.pack(side="left")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def cmd(self):
        os.system("start cmd /a")

    def notepad(self):
        os.system("start notepad")


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
sys.exit()
```

Second way:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.create_widgets2()
        self.create_widgets3()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello, what would you like help with today?"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.hi_there
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

    def create_widgets2(self):
        self.notepad = tk.Button(self)
        self.notepad["text"] = "Launch Notepad"
        self.notepad["command"] = self.notepad
        self.notepad.pack(side="right")

    def create_widgets3(self):
        self.hi = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi["text"] = "Launch CMD"
        self.hi["command"] = self.cmd
        self.hi.pack(side="left")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def cmd(self):
        os.system("start cmd /a")

    def notepad(self):
        os.system("start notepad")


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
sys.exit()
```

I apologize for any language mistakes, but English is not my native language.